# C#, Visual Studio 2022 : how can I access a GeometryModel3D in a Viewport3D to be able to loop within a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2022, backgroundworker, viewport3d

Here's the relevant code from the MainWindow class.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    readonly Model3DGroup myModel3DGroup = new Model3DGroup();
    readonly ModelVisual3D myModelVisual3D = new ModelVisual3D();
    readonly PerspectiveCamera myPCamera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    readonly DirectionalLight myDirectionalLight = new DirectionalLight();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateEnvironment();
        CreateCube();
    }

    private void CreateEnvironment()
    {
        myPCamera.Position = new Point3D(1, 1, 1);
        myPCamera.LookDirection = new Vector3D(-1, -1, -1);
        myPCamera.UpDirection = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
        myPCamera.FieldOfView = 60;
        myPCamera.FarPlaneDistance = 30;

        viewPort.Camera = myPCamera;

        myDirectionalLight.Color = Colors.White;
        myDirectionalLight.Direction = new Vector3D(-1, -1, -1);

        myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(myDirectionalLight);

        myModelVisual3D.Content = myModel3DGroup;

        viewPort.Children.Add(myModelVisual3D);
    }

    private void CreateCube()
    {
        cube = new Cube(0, 0, 0, 1, 255, 255, 0, 0);

        myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(cube.cubeModel);
    }

    private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Left:
                cube.ForceRotateCube(Cube.RotationAxis.Y, -1);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void MainWindow_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Left:
                cube.SlowCubeRotation();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant code from the `Cube` class:

```
internal class Cube
{
    public GeometryModel3D cubeModel;

    public BackgroundWorker cubeWorker;

    double yAngle { get; set; } = 0;
    double ySpeed { get; set; } = 0;
    int ySpeedInc { get; set; } = 1;

    public Cube(double x, double y, double z, double s, byte a, byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        cubeModel = new GeometryModel3D
        {
            Geometry = myMeshGeometry3D,
            Material = GetMaterial(a, r, g, b),
            Transform = SetStartingTransformation()
        };
    }

    public void ForceRotateCube(RotationAxis axis, int dir) // axis: X, Y, Z - dir : 1, -1
    {   
        // first lets increase the speed of the rotation from 0 to whatever
        ySpeed += ySpeedInc * .01 * dir;
    
        // next increase the angle by that speed so the angle position is different
        yAngle += ySpeed;
    
        RotateTransform3D myRotateTransform3D = new RotateTransform3D();
        AxisAngleRotation3D myAxisAngleRotation3d = new AxisAngleRotation3D();
        myAxisAngleRotation3d.Axis = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
        myAxisAngleRotation3d.Angle = yAngle;
        myRotateTransform3D.Rotation = myAxisAngleRotation3d;
    
        cubeModel.Transform = myRotateTransform3D;
    }

    public void SlowCubeRotation()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SlowCubeRotation");

        if(cubeWorker == null)
        {
            cubeWorker = new();
            cubeWorker.DoWork += SlowTransformation;
        }

        cubeWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public void SlowTransformation(object? sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        taskRunning = true;

        while (Math.Abs(ySpeed) > .1)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(ySpeed) <= .1) ySpeed = 0;

            // first lets reverse the speed of the rotation
            ySpeed -= ySpeedInc * .001;

            // next decrease the angle by that speed so the angle position is different
            yAngle += ySpeed;

            RotateTransform3D myRotateTransform3D = new RotateTransform3D();
            AxisAngleRotation3D myAxisAngleRotation3d = new AxisAngleRotation3D();
            myAxisAngleRotation3d.Axis = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
            myAxisAngleRotation3d.Angle = yAngle;
            myRotateTransform3D.Rotation = myAxisAngleRotation3d;
            
            try
            {
                cubeModel.Transform = myRotateTransform3D;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        taskRunning = false;
    }
}
```

I'm sure you already know the error I'm getting:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll.
> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I was able to send the cube object created in the Main class to the Method in a previous attempt, but it didn't update the UI until it was finished. I'd like the Cube object to be able transform itself based on its own properties and the UI gets updated from there.

I've tried invoking without success, but it's possible I wasn't using it properly. I've deleted all that process and reverted back to my basic code to get a fresh start on the issue.

Comment: You simply cannot access the UI elements from a non-UI thread. You have to make sure your computation is on non-UI data to run it on a non-UI thread.